# Plot a rotated, translated circle in 3D space

Tags: math, plot, gnuplot

[Here is a little image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3W2v.png) from my current situation. At the moment I'm trying to plot a circle centered around the red vector in the front. And the circle should touch the blue vector.
But I can tweak the parameters on my own (and most certainly there are other circles to come).

So what I would like is a general method to **plot a circle with an arbitrary center point in 3d space that is rotated around an arbitrary axis**.

The code below is my current draft. It draws a horizontal circle around an arbitrary center point, but the rotation-part is still missing.

```
set parametric
set urange [0:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
 [..]
# radius
r = 0.1
# center (d,e,k) 
d = 0.1
e = 0.2
k = 0.3
fTx(u,v) = d+r*cos(v)
fTy(u,v) = e+r*sin(v)
fTz(u,v) = k         

splot [..]  ,\
      fTx(u,v), fTy(u,v), fTz(u,v)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rotate the points of the circle using the [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). For example for rotating by an angle `th` about the x axis, the points `(fTx, fTy, fTz)` are multiplied with `Rx(th)`:

```
         ( 1     0         0    )
Rx(th) = ( 0  cos(th)  -sin(th) )
         ( 0  sin(th)   cos(th) )
```

For rotating by th=24°, your Gnuplot script can be extended as follows:

```
th = 24.0*pi/180
rotx(u,v) = fTx(u,v)
roty(u,v) = cos(th)*fTy(u,v) - sin(th)*fTz(u,v)
rotz(u,v) = sin(th)*fTy(u,v) + cos(th)*fTz(u,v)

splot rotx(u,v), roty(u,v), rotz(u,v)
```

Rotating about another axis is straight forward.

Thinking again about the subject, it might be easier to rotate first before moving the rotated circle to `(d, e, k)`:

```
set parametric
set urange [0:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
# radius
r = 0.1
# center (d,e,k)
d = 0.1
e = 0.2
k = 0.3
# rotation angles (th, ..)
th = 24.0*pi/180.0

fTx(u,v) = r*cos(v)
fTy(u,v) = r*sin(v)
fTz(u,v) = 0      

rotx(u,v) = fTx(u,v)
roty(u,v) = cos(th)*fTy(u,v) - sin(th)*fTz(u,v)
rotz(u,v) = sin(th)*fTy(u,v) + cos(th)*fTz(u,v)

movx(u,v) = d + rotx(u, v)
movy(u,v) = e + roty(u, v)
movz(u,v) = k + rotz(u, v)

splot movx(u,v), movy(u,v), movz(u,v)
```

Comment: At first thank you very much! It works nearly perfect and the math isn't a magic black box:) My only concern is, that the x and y axis seems to be switched. Your code gives me a rotation around the y axis (https://i.imgur.com/FVM9XXM.png) and a matrix for y gives me a rotation around x. (z axis works as expected). Do you have any ideas where this could come from?

Comment: No, I don't know. But I would not care that much. I would just take the matrix or the combination of matrices that works. Maybe one of me or you or gnuplot or wikipedia has a different definition of  x and y. Or all of us :)